# How is the exit condition "x=10" in this loop " for (x=0;x=10;x++)" always true?

Tags: c#, c

i have typed this code and ran it , and it runs infinitely , i couldn't understand why since it should have stopped once x gets to 10

i expected it to stop at 10 since it started from 0 and incremented by 1 until it gets to 10

Comment: You do not compare x to anything, rather you set its value to 10 over and over and over again. Try < or > instead of =

Comment: Do not tag both C and C# when asking about one of the languages.

Comment: x == 10 is a condition. Also: Better code defensively, ie not for an exact match but for things like x <= 10 or x >= 10..

Answer (score 1):

`for` loops do not have an exit condition. They have a continue condition. When the middle condition is tested, the loop continues if it is true. `x = 10` is an assignment expression. It assigns 10 to `x`, and the value of the assignment expression is the new value of `x`, so it is always 10 (or, if `x` is a `_Bool`, it is 1), which serves as “true” for the condition. You may have wanted `x == 10`, which is a comparison expression. But that is true only when `x` is 10, so the loop would never execute even the first iteration. You need to a condition to continue the loop, not to exit it, so you want `x < 10`.